# Making App On One PC And Publishing Using Another PC

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I am using a developers account on one laptop (Macbook Pro) and now I want to start working on a second account which is on my other laptop (Macbook Santa Rosa). The other laptop is slow and outdated to run Android Studio so my question is:

Can I build APK using Macbook Pro and then publish it on Play Console using Macbook Santa Rosa?

Since Google have strict rules, will this cause any trouble for me in the future? If my first account gets suspended, will the second one get suspended too? Does Android Studio store any information about the laptop inside APK?

Comment: Is there any reason for you to put capital letters on all of your words ? Can't you just use the same account on both machines ?

Comment: As I Mentioned In My Question, I'm Planning To Start A New Account On My Second Laptop But Second Laptop Is Slow. So I Want To Know If It's Okay If I Build APK From My First Laptop And Upload It On Play Console Using Second One. Would Be Very Greatful If People Who Knows About Android Development & Rules Of Play Console Comment, Instead Of People Who Teaches 3rd Grade.